# Could two distinct prime number $p,q$ both be the quadratic residue of another prime $t$ with certain constraints?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem: let $p,q$ be two distinct odd prime numbers with
$$p \equiv 1 \pmod 8;\quad  q \equiv 3 \pmod 4 ; \quad  \left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = 1.$$

I wonder if $\left(\frac{p}{t}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{q}{t}\right)$ could both be $1$ or not ($\forall\ t$ is a prime where $t \neq p,q$).
I tried to apply the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity but still, I cannot see a clear connection between $\left(\frac{t}{q}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{t}{p}\right)$. Is there anyone could help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $p\not\equiv 3\pmod 4$, we have $\left(\frac pq\right)=\left(\frac qp\right)$ and $\left(\frac pt\right)=\left(\frac tp\right)$. If we additionally demand $t\not\equiv 3\pmod 4$, we will also have $\left(\frac qt\right)=\left(\frac tq\right)$. So in order to have $\left(\frac tp\right)=\left(\frac tq\right)=1$, we impose the following modular restrictions on $t$:

- $t\equiv 1\pmod 4$
- $t\equiv a\pmod p$ for some quadratic residue $a\bmod p$
- $t\equiv b\pmod q$ for some quadratic residue $b\bmod q$

Of course, we can simply take $a=b=1$, and as $4,p,q$ are coprime, we only need

- $t\equiv 1\pmod{4pq}$.

Such primes $t$ exist by Dirichlet.

---

Note that ultimately we only used that $p,q$ are distinct odd primes. And even distinctness is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can both be $1$. For example $p=41$, $q=31$, $t=5$ or $t=83$.